# Crystal Report Licensing

Tags: crystal-reports, licensing

I am wanting to upgrade some copies of SAP Crystal Reports.  I am working for a US company but located in another country and am thinking I can buy it from the US rather than Australia, which is much more expensive.  Is anybody familiar with the SAP/CR licensing policy.  I know MS has gone to a licensing policy where a copy of their product bought in the US is not valid if used in another region.

We use CR on the client to create reports from a C# application.

Comment: interesting question- i would probably try and contact SAP directly. i have to admit i reside in the UK but bought from the US as it worked out a substancial amount less!

Comment: I think as much as you'd like to avoid giving SAP the opportunity to say no (by calling to ask) you should take Lee's advice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think as much as you'd like to avoid giving SAP the opportunity to say no (by calling to ask) you should take Lee's advice. (the comment against your question)

It might save money on the licensing but there are liability concerns beyond piracy. Such as support/warranty, liability should you need to sue SAP (in the event of negligence related software failure), etc. Not only that, but if you correspond by email and/or record phone calls you can hold them accountable should the sales representative misinform you.

It could be related to the agreements being adjusted for each region, to be aligned to local applicable laws. That said, maybe a unique situation arises if you bought copies from resellers that were International? Sounds complicated!

Heck, it might even boil down to where you are using the software (i.e. a webserver) and/or the country from which the payment was made. (i.e. You have a regional office)

Good luck with it.